# iOS Sharing Extension app icon not changed to new

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-extensions

I have changed the appicon in xcode project. But My sharing extension keeps showing old one. When I delete appicon files then it shows nothing but when I add again it shows me old one.

By the way it shows correct in the simulator but not in device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete app, reboot device and install again. It's work for me. 
As I understand, iOS save app icon and launch screen to cache after first app running and load it from cache until rebooting.

Comment: Do you reboot device before installing again?

Comment: It has updated itself. Maybe it was done after reboot.

Comment: I tried clean build, uninstalling, rebooting... nothing helped. My share extension won't show my new icon.

Comment: Simply rebooting worked for me. No need to delete the app.